# Can I configure different Devhub orgs per SFDX project?

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub

I have multiple Devhub orgs. One belongs to my employer. Others belong to external companies that I do consulting work for via my employer.

The latter includes Devhub orgs that define the packaging namespace that I need to reference in the `sfdx-project.json` for that consulting work.

If I try and directly use the VS Code `>SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org...` command it issues the following CLI command:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias ScratchOrgName --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
```

That fails with the message:

> We don’t recognize this namespace: *NamespaceInSfdxProjectJson*. Did you register it in your Dev Hub org?

That makes sense, as my default devhub org in the CLI is configured to my be my employers. However, in this case I need to use another Devhub that is configured already in the CLI.

If I was doing this manually I could add a `--targetdevhubusername` to the CLI command to point it at the correct Devhub for the project. Or I could use [`force:config:set`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm#cli_reference_set) to change the **defaultdevhubusername**. Neither of these options is ideal as I need to keep track of which devhub is applicable to the current project.

Is it possible to configure the correct Devhub to use against each project?

Answer (score 9):

My mistake. The `force:config:set` has options to set the value for both the current directory **OR** globally.

E.g. Omit the `-g` and `--global` parameters to set the config for the current directory/project.

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=devhubForCurrentProject@devhub.com
```